# Arduino and Android based PC

Tags: android, automation, arduino

I have plans to integrate an arduino board (not broght) with a Android 4.0 based PC (1GB RAM, 1,5Ghz Proc, HDMI, wi-fi). Is possible to use this android pc to control the arduino board and act as controller? So i can use the power of android to automate my home.

Here is the android that i have: AK802 Mini Android 4.0 Network Media Player w/ Wi-Fi / HDMI / TF / USB - Black (4GB / 1GB DDR III)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use ADK with Android devices that can act as an USB host, starting from Android 2.3.4

For more information you can check the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to talk beetwen Arduino and Android: Android Debug Bridge (ADB) MicroBridge mode and [Android Open Accessory](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) Protocol (only for devices with Android version > 2.3.4).

For MicroBridge mode see this work example: [USB data transfer between Android and Arduino](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino3.php)

Answer (score 0):

The AK802/MK802 Android 4.0 media players have USB host, so there shouldn't be a need for ADK/Microbridge/IOIO. Try plugging it in and checking for /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0. You'll still need a way to read/write to this device from your Android app for which you will probably need some native code.

Alternatively, if you don't care about the Android UI, you can simply install a generic Linux such as Ubuntu. From there, everything should be pretty much the same as on a normal PC.

Finally, you can think about a wireless link over Bluetooth. Android supports Bluetooth out of the box, and USB dongles are only a few dollars these days, and an Arduino shield should be about $18.